# MyBatis doesn't return all the results from the query

Tags: sql, associations, mybatis

## The Problem

I have a query that returns 17 records.  When I use MyBatis with a map that has an `<association>` it returns 6 records. *Note that this doesn't happen with my other maps, I have many other maps with associations that all work fine.*

**Query:**

```
    with leave_counts as 
    (
        select leave_type_id, count(llm.leave_id) as count
        from lw_leave_master llm
        group by leave_type_id
    )
    select llt.leave_type_id, llt.leave_type_abbr_tx, 
            llt.leave_type_desc_tx, lc.count as count_nm
    from lw_leave_type llt
        join leave_counts lc on lc.leave_type_id=llt.leave_type_id
    order by llt.leave_type_abbr_tx
```

**Map:**

```
<resultMap id="typeCountMap" type="mypackage.myclass">
    <result property="count" column="count_nm"/>
    <association property="type" resultMap="package.myMap"/>
</resultMap>


<resultMap id="myMap" type="mypackage.myclass2">
    <result property="id" column="leave_type_id"/>
    <result property="abbr" column="leave_type_abbr_tx"/>
    <result property="description" column="leave_type_desc_tx"/>
</resultMap>
```

The `<association>` in `typeCountMap` refers to the map `myMap`.

This returns 6 records every time.  Grabbing the actual query run from the logger and running it manually returns 17 records.

## Solutions?

**There are two things I can do to get MyBatis to return all 17 records**

**#1**

If I remove the `lc.count as count_nm` from my query I get all 17 records returned (just with no values associated with them)

```
    with leave_counts as 
    (
        select leave_type_id, count(llm.leave_id) as count
        from lw_leave_master llm
        group by leave_type_id
    )
    select llt.leave_type_id, llt.leave_type_abbr_tx, 
            llt.leave_type_desc_tx
    from lw_leave_type llt
        join leave_counts lc on lc.leave_type_id=llt.leave_type_id
    order by llt.leave_type_abbr_tx
```

This is obviously not a good solution, but I wanted to include this in case it would help you figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**#2**

If I replace the association with the contents of the other map everything works as expected.

```
<resultMap id="typeCountMap" type="mypackage.myclass1">
    <result property="count" column="count_nm"/>        
    <result property="type.id" column="leave_type_id"/>
    <result property="type.abbr" column="leave_type_abbr_tx"/>
    <result property="type.description" column="leave_type_desc_tx"/>
</resultMap>
```

This obviously is what I'll do if I don't find another solution, since this does work.  It would just be nice to use the `<association>` like I have in other maps.

I should note that I am using MyBatis 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem, but it's something to try. I have to post here because I don't have enough rep to leave a comment.

Try adding a column attribute to your association and marking the ID column in the second map:

```
<resultMap id="typeCountMap" type="mypackage.myclass">
    <result property="count" column="count_nm"/>
    <association property="type" column="leave_type_id" resultMap="package.myMap"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="myMap" type="mypackage.myclass2">
    <id property="id" column="leave_type_id"/>
    <result property="abbr" column="leave_type_abbr_tx"/>
    <result property="description" column="leave_type_desc_tx"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: According to the mybatis documentation http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html, attribute `column` is only needed for Nested Select, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this same problem. I believe the issue was related to my main resultMap with the association in it not having an id column while my association's resultMap did have an id column. My results were getting grouped by the associations id column.

To correct the issue I selected the row number in my query and added an id to my main resultMap pointing to the row number column.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 3.1.1 you can define just <id column="leave_type_id" /> without property attribute
If you're not using 3.1.1 you can add <result property="abbr" column="leave_type_id" /> on top of the list to include field into cache key calculation for association, later re-definition will assign correct value

Comment: Also you can use <id column="fake_column_name" />;. It will skip caching because value for the column is null and id is unique value that mybatis will only use for calculation, mybatis will also skip mapping since it is not real i.e. does not refer to any column. All of them are hacks, so probably you should not rely on the behavior.

Comment: I encontered the same issue. Adding <id column="fake_column_name"> didn't help me to get all records. Instead I got only 1 record. So i decided to use real id column name.

Comment: Adding <id column="fake_column_name" /> helped me. MyBatis version 3.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the line  `<result property="id" column="leave_type_id"/>`

with `<id property="id" column="leave_type_id"/>`.

In mybatis you should not miss to specify the id column it may mess up with your result set.