# MyBatis ignores unique identifier in multiple associations using columnPrefix

Tags: sql, associations, mybatis

I have a problem with MyBatis (3.2.7) similar to these [MyBatis doesn't return all the results from the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223094/mybatis-doesnt-return-all-the-results-from-the-query) , [Not all results returned by MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905712/not-all-results-returned-by-mybatis) and http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Not-all-rows-returned-by-query-being-mapped-td4025936.html where I use multiple associations with columnPrefix:

```
<association property="object" columnPrefix="o_" resultMap="package.ObjectMapper.BaseResultMap"/>
```

These point to result maps in other MyBatis generated xml files each having an ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="package.ObjectMapper" >
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="sometype" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Thu May 21 14:14:47 CEST 2015.
    -->
    <id column="ID" property="id" jdbcType="DECIMAL" javaType="sometype" />
    <result column="number" property="number" jdbcType="DECIMAL" javaType="long" />
  </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

Now I get three results from the query. MyBatis will return only one result while the results mapped in one of the associations are unique. I explicitly need to add

```
<id column="o_id"/>
<association property="object" columnPrefix="o_" resultMap="package.ObjectMapper.BaseResultMap"/>
```

in current xml file for that association to make MyBatis understand that the results are unique and return me three results.

What I understand is that MyBatis tries to be smart and merge the results where it thinks that multiple results are the same. And that I need to explicitly provide the id tag to tell MyBatis that they are not the same to return me three unique results.

Is there a way to disable (configuration?) this in MyBatis for all mappers so that it will always return me three results and let the me decide which fields should form a combined unique id? Or let MyBatis deep check associations for unique values?

Note: This could be the case for other mappers too. So adding id tag in all the mappers doesn't sound like right solution.